# Capitalize first letter in each word with symbols in sentence

Tags: java, string, uppercase

I have a database that stores strings that people wrote. Those string for example defines the name of movies.

In order to overcome duplicates and some other things, I did that no matter what the user typed, it will make every first letter capital. In that manner, all of the strings will be saved in the same way.

The way I do it is by using:

```
String[] words = query.split( "\\s+" );
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String Word = words[i].replaceAll( "[^\\w]", "" );
    words[i] = Word.substring( 0, 1 ).toUpperCase() + Word.substring( 1 );
}
query = TextUtils.join( " ", words );
```

However, I faced a problem when I tried to type something like: Tom & Jerry.

In that case, I got an error with the `&`. Do I just need to set if conditions to check for every letter such as `&, (, ), $` and so on?

Comment: Why diid you do `replaceAll( "[^\\w]", "" )`? That's the cause of your problem.

Comment: The problem is that `&` turns into the empty string, then when you try to substring, the string is blank. Do a check for length > 1 should fix it

Comment: I'd seek a solution that replaces the first `[a-z]` in the string witth it's uppercase value. It could be done with a regex. `"^([^a-z]*)([a-z])(.*)"` then if a match use the three groups to reconstruct a new string with toupper on the second group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toUpperCase` handles non-letter characters just fine, and just returns the same character. The problem with your code is that it assumes each `word` is non-empty, which is no longer true after you remove the special characters.

To make a long story short, just keep the special characters, and you should be OK:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String word = words[i];
    words[i] = word.substring( 0, 1 ).toUpperCase() + word.substring( 1 );
}
```